# Вставка данных в несколько дивов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу догадаться, как всавить данные из массива JSON в каждый див.

[image: Данные представляют собой массив вида]

Нужно вставить в от в такой див коих 9 штук.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class='nextprod'  src="" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Вот код которым я это пытаюсь сделать, но так ничего не вставляется.

```
if (data.contents) {

                let prod='';
                let ctn2 = data.contents.length;
                for(var ix=0; ix<ctn2; ix++) {
                    var countSrck=data.contents[1][ix]['src'].length;
                    var countAlter=data.contents[1][ix]['alternate'].length;
                       for(var isrk=0; isrk<countSrck; isrk++){
                          var srck=data.contents[1][ix]['src'][isrk];
                       for(var ialter=0; ialter<countAlter;ialter++){
                           var alter=data.contents[1][ix]['alternate'][ialter];
                           $('img.nextprod').attr({'src':srck,'alt':alter});
                       }
                       }
                   $('div.caption p').append(data.contents[1][ix]['small_text']);

                }

            }
```

Как вставить в каждый див свой контент? И как это сделать более грамотно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
    myObj = {
        "0":{ "name":"Ford", 
              "models":"Fiesta",
              "price":"10000",
              "image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Пистолет_Макарова.png/300px-Пистолет_Макарова.png"
        },
        "1":{ "name":"BMW", 
              "models":"X5",
              "price":"10000",
              "image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Пистолет_Макарова.png/300px-Пистолет_Макарова.png"
        },
        "2":{ "name":"Fiat",
              "models":"Panda",
              "price":"10000",
              "image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Пистолет_Макарова.png/300px-Пистолет_Макарова.png"
       }
    };
 
for (i in myObj) {
    $wrapper.append('<div class="some-class"><p>' + myObj[i].name + '</p>' +
    '<p>' + myObj[i].models + '</p>' +
    '<p>' + myObj[i].price + '</p>' +
    '<img src="' + myObj[i].image + '" /></div>');
}
```

```css
.some-class{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Привет а можешь подсказать как отключить кеширование js скриптов в 
гугл браузере. А то я тут нашёл ctr+F5, Disable cache. Но все равно подкеширует. И только что измененный файл остается неизмененным. Ну и как его нормально продебажить в PHP storm&

Comment: @dpi скорее всего кеширует хостинг, а ctrl+f5 100% сносит текущие кеши сайта

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data.contents) {
  let $divThumbs = $(".thumbnail");
  let ctn2 = Math.min(data.contents.length, $divThumbs.length);
  for (var ix = 0; ix < ctn2; ix++) {
    let $divThumb = $($divThumbs[ix]);
    $divThumb.empty();

    let countSrck = data.contents[ix]['src'].length;
    let countAlter = data.contents[ix]['alternate'].length;
    for(var isrk = 0; isrk < Math.min(countSrck, countAlter); isrk++) {
      let srck = data.contents[ix].src[isrk];
      let alter = data.contents[ix].alternate[isrk];
      let $img = $("<img class='nextprod'/>");
      $img.attr({'src': srck, 'alt':alter});
      $divThumb.append($img);
    }
    let $divCaption = $("<div class="caption"><h3>Thumbnail label</h3><p></p></div>");
    $divCaption.find("p").text(data.contents[ix].small_text);
    $divThumb.append($divCaption);
  }
}
```

Comment: чет не работает(  P.S. данные все время приходят. А вот вставка не работает.